# What does MPI_File_Open

Tags: mpi, openmp

I can't understand this instruction what MPI_File_Open and related MPI_seek and MPI_read does. Is there someone who can help me?

With the instruction MPI_File_Open the file is read simultaneously between all processors when I run the program? For example, if I specify mpirun -n 4 etc, is the file read by all four processors?

This is the code:

```
MPI_File fh;
MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, image, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
for (i = 1 ; i <= rows ; i++) {
        MPI_File_seek(fh, 3*(start_row + i-1) * width + 3*start_col, MPI_SEEK_SET);
        tmpbuf = offset(src, i, 3, cols*3+6);
        MPI_File_read(fh, tmpbuf, cols*3, MPI_BYTE, &status);
    }
MPI_File_close(&fh);
```

Is there a way I can turn this into openMP or optimize it? I tried to modify the code like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
for (i = 1 ; i <= rows ; i++) {
        MPI_File_seek(fh, 3*(start_row + i-1) * width + 3*start_col, MPI_SEEK_SET);
        tmpbuf = offset(src, i, 3, cols*3+6);
        MPI_File_read(fh, tmpbuf, cols*3, MPI_BYTE, &status);
    }
```

Running the program with this modification I don't get any speedup of the execution. Runs at the same time as code with MPI only. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your OpenMP modification is probably not legal. the MPI process keeps internal a file pointer, and and you let each thread update it. Between the seek and the read you have a race condition.

Comment: 1) I have no skill in MPI, but just reading the [doc of Open MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.1/man3/MPI_File_open.3.php) answers your first question: the file is opened and read by all the MPI processes.

Comment: 2) Does the first version without OpenMP give you the expected result? If no, OpenMP won't fix it... If yes, what are you trying to do with OpenMP? Speeding-up the I/Os? If yes, not only the OpenMP code is flawed as pointed out by @VictorEijkhout, but we miss many informations: are you running MPI on a single machine or on a cluster? How many cores has the machine?

Comment: 3) unless you are reading/writing on a **NVME** SSD, parallel I/Os generally do not give significant speed-up. On a HDD they are even most of time slower than non-parallel.

Comment: To reinforce @PierU's comment - MPI's parallel I/O capabilities are targeted at the kind of 'big iron' equipped with parallel file systems - ie the applications you/we write are served by an o/s which understands what to do with the parallel read and write requests, and sends them off to a networked file system with multiple hardware paths to and from SSDs or spinning HDDs. On that kind of kit parallel I/O can be tremendous speed up.  On my laptop, not so much.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark No argument on the "big iron" aspect. However, MPI File I/O is also very convenient for constructing a single file from many interleaved bits. All that "View" stuff. But both your and mine arguments pertain mostly to writing. For the OP it's largely irrelevant.